# avoid reload page after innerHTML update with function call

Tags: javascript, html

When changing a html element with a function using innerHTML, the html element changes, but immediately the page reloads and the element is set back to his original value.
How can this be avoided ?

I realise that I am probably missing something very essential and feel a little bit embarrassed launching this question. But, I googled around for this problem and I could not find an answer. If someone could take a minute to put me on the right track in this forest of html, javascript, css an php where I try to find my way, I would very much appreciate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Question stackoverflow</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p id="test"> This should be changed after button click </p>
            <form>
                <button onclick="test()">Refresh</button>
            </form>     
        </div>
        <script>
        function test(){
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "replaced";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to ignore the default event to prevent the post back. That is if you don't want to post back to the server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Question stackoverflow</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p id="test"> This should be changed after button click </p>
            <form>
                <button onclick="test(event)">Refresh</button>
            </form>     
        </div>
       <script>
        function test(event){
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "replaced";
            event.preventDefault()
        }
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to put your button in a `<form>` , and add the attribute `type="button"` to your `<button>`.
**Forms will submit and refresh** the page, I think this is the reason of your problem.

By the way, **don't write your script at the end of your file**, put it in the `<head>` and add the attribute `onload="myInitFunction();"` to your `<body>`.
The way you do it is a bad habit.

**Another way to proceed:**
link your script as exernal file in your `<head>`
`<script src="pathtojsfile/script.js"></script>`
Instead of doing

```
<body onload="myInitFunction();">[...]</body>
```

You can write this at the end of your script.js

```
window.onload = myInitFunction;
```

**One last thing :**
Use `element.innerHTML` when you need to insert something like an HTML block.
If you just want to add text, use `element.textContent = "Some text.";`

Comment: Does your recommendation about putting the script in the <head> also apply for functions implementing XMLHttpRequest ?
In the examples that I found for this type of page updates the script was put in the <body>

Comment: @PaulR it applies for everything, because this is the real correct way to use your JS code ;-) 
I often do some AJAX too and I always link my script in the head. Don't worry for XMLHttpRequest, it should have no consequence if the functions you made are well called !

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advise. 
from a gratefull novice novice :)

Comment: @PaulR You're welcome ! Don't forget to accept my answer if it solved your problem (click under the note of my answer), and good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add `type="button"` in the `button`.

```
<button type="button" onclick="test()">Refresh</button>
```

By default, the type of the button is considered as `submit`, thus submits the form on clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers. You gave me a clear guidance for further exploration.
I think I got the essence: when a form is submitted to the server it triggers a complete reload of the page, which is again read from his initial url with his initial state.

Thanks once to everyone for the valuable input. Unfortunately I can only tick one answer, but all answers where answers to my question, complementing to one another and even giving related additional advise.